# Python Pygame collisions

Tags: python, pygame

I am doing a program where a ball have to travel in a maze with help of gravity (for now no user interaction) .

I already have the maze generation code and the ball code; but in my main program i can't figure out how to stop the ball when it collide with a wall of my maze.

here is my code:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import random
import pygame
import sys
from labyrinthe import * #generateur de labyrinthe aleatoire


image_file = os.path.expanduser("ball.png")

gravity = +1



class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(10,10 , 10, 10)
        self.speed = [0, 0]
        area = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        self.width, self.height = area.width, area.height

    def update(self):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed)
        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > self.height:
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]          #effet rebond de la balle

        self.rect.top = clip(self.rect.top, 0, self.height) #collision taille de la fenetre
        self.rect.bottom = clip(self.rect.bottom, 0, self.height)#//





def clip(val, minval, maxval):

    return min(max(val, minval), maxval)








class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 10, 10)







os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()


pygame.display.set_caption("GravityMaze")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
ball = Ball()
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walls = []

level = lance()
print(level)
#Lecture de "level" pour la creation des murs
x = y = 0
start_rect=pygame.Rect(10,0,10, 10)
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "*":
            Wall((x, y))
        if col == "s":      
            end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 10)

        x += 10
    y+= 10
    x = 0
friction = 0.90
running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(60)

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit()

        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
            sys.exit()

    ball.speed = [friction*s for s in ball.speed]# effet gravite
    ball.speed[1] += gravity######################//
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(ball.image, ball.rect)
    ball.update()
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)# creation des murs du laby
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)#case de fin
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), start_rect)# case de depart
    pygame.display.flip()
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I actually put my walls and my ball into a sprite group and used the spritecollideany() pygame function.
hope it will help someone.